# Trying to move something without using position:relative

Tags: html, css

I'm just wondering if it's possible to move this (image1) to (image2). I don't want to use `position:relative` as that would ruin my design in bootstrap.

Image 1 (I don't want it here)

http://puu.sh/ciBCF/3d1d6b202a.png

Image 2 ( I want it here)

http://puu.sh/ciBET/0f44f62b3f.png

My code for CSS

```
  .results {
        color: red;
        display: block;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align:center;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold; 
        background: #232323;
        color:red;
        font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
        font-size: 150%;

        }
```

Thanks in advance :)

UPDATE WHOLE CODE:

```
<?php
 session_start();
include ('../includes/config.php'); 
include ('../includes/header.php'); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<!--start header-->
<div class="h_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
         <a href="index.php"><img src="../images/logo.png"> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cssmenu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
          <li  class="active"><a href="about.php"><span>About</span></a></li>
       <li class="has-sub"><a href="service.php"><span>Gallery</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="last"><a href="contact.php"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
     <div class="clear"></div>

                         <div class="search">
                    <h2>search</h2>
            <form>
                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Your search...">
                <input type="submit" value="">
            </form>
        </div>

                                         <div class="search1">

            <h2>login/Register</h2>

            <form action="" method="POST">

            <label>Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="password" name="username" required />
            <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" class="submit" />
                <br><br>
                <center>
                <h2><p><a href="register.php">Register</a></p></h2>
                </center>
    </form> 
    </div>







<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];



    $password = strip_tags($password); 
$password = md5($password); // md5 is used to encrypt your password to make it more secure.





    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows!=0)
    {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $dbusername=$row['username'];
    $dbpassword=$row['password'];
    }

    if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword)
    {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['sess_user']=$username;

    /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: member.php");
    }
    } else {
    echo "<div class='results'>Invalid username or password</div>";
    }

} else {
    echo "All fields are required!";
}
}



?>
    </div>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- start content -->
<div class="content_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <h2 class="style">About us</h2>
        <div class="about">
             <div class="cont-grid-img img_style">
                <img src="../images/about_pic.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
           <div class="cont-grid">
           <div class="abt-style">
            <p class="style top">We are a company built on dreams. And these dreams inspire us to create innovative products that enhance human mobility and benefit society. We see "The Power of Dreams" as a way of thinking that guides us and inspires us to move forward. The strength of our company comes from this philosophy—based on the visionary principles of our founder, Soichiro Honda.Our success in the global marketplace is the result of our continued investment in America's future. We thank our customers for the support and trust they've shown us. We look forward to challenging ourselves to create new products and services that bring value to our customers and society during the next 50 years.</p>
            </div>
             <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="about-p top">
                <p class="style">Honda's global lineup consists of the Fit, Civic, Accord, Insight, CR-V, CR-Z, Legend and two versions of the Odyssey, one for North America, and a smaller vehicle sold internationally. An early proponent of developing vehicles to cater to different needs and markets worldwide, Honda's lineup varies by country and may have vehicles exclusive to that region. A few examples are the latest Honda Odyssey minivan and the Ridgeline, Honda's first light-duty uni-body pickup truck. Both were designed and engineered primarily in North America and are produced there. Other example of exclusive models includes the Honda Civic five-door hatchback sold in Europe.

Honda's automotive manufacturing ambitions can be traced back to 1963, with the Honda T360, a kei car truck built for the Japanese market.[27] This was followed by the two-door roadster, the Honda S500 also introduced in 1963. In 1965, Honda built a two-door commercial delivery van, called the Honda L700. Honda's first four-door sedan was not the Accord, but the air-cooled, four-cylinder, gasoline-powered Honda 1300 in 1969. The Civic was a hatchback that gained wide popularity internationally, but it wasn't the first two-door hatchback built. That was the Honda N360, another Kei car that was adapted for international sale as the N600. The Civic, which appeared in 1972 and replaced the N600 also had a smaller sibling that replaced the air-cooled N360, called the Honda Life that was water-cooled.

The Honda Life represented Honda's efforts in competing in the kei car segment, offering sedan, delivery van and small pick-up platforms on a shared chassis. The Life StepVan had a novel approach that, while not initially a commercial success, appears to be an influence in vehicles with the front passengers sitting behind the engine, a large cargo area with a flat roof and a liftgate installed in back, and utilizing a transversely installed engine with a front-wheel-drive powertrain.</p>

        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="copy">
            <p class="w3-link">©&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="f_nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Skype</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Linked in</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could we ee the login form HTML ? Can you put an error <span> in the place you want message to appear ?

Comment: @Billy Code updated above

Comment: @Ariana where is your div ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek It's listed in my PHP http://puu.sh/ciCMr/28a05187ce.png

Comment: @Ariana i mean where is your div in the code ?

Comment: could you not echo out the whole form again from php with the results div in the right place ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek What div are you talking about?

Comment: Put the php up here aswell.

Comment: @Ariana div with class results .

Comment: @Billy Code fully updated above

Comment: @ProllyGeek Code updated above, full

Comment: @Ariana let me know if my solution works for you .

Comment: Why are you trying to move the message with CSS? Its *your* code - simply place the message where you want it to appear in the markup. Put the php methods at the top of the page (above the html), write the login response to a variable, then `echo` the variable wherever you want it.

Comment: There are 6 positioning properties: static, absolute, fixed, relative, initial and inherit. 

The guys at twitter use CSS (and possibly LESS, which also compiles to CSS) which means that they have used one of these, or they haven't set the property at all.

Comment: If they haven't set the property at all, they are using static which is the same as relative but doesn't use left and top. 

If relative is breaking the page, like you said, then there are 4 possible values for position remaining: absolute, fixed, initial and inherit. 

inherit isn't a value itself but rather a pointer to it's parents property value. 

initial is also just a pointer to the original value. 

Now you are left with two possible values: absolute and fixed. 

If the element doesn't move with the page when scrolling, the element is using fixed, otherwise it's using absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If css 3 is ok for you, then "translate", transformation may help?

e.g:

```
.results {
  ...
  transform: translate(0px,-200px); 
}
```

you may have to set appropriate value instead of -200px.

**Update:**

After looking at your code.

Why not place the "php" section where you need to show the error message?

**Update 2**

Putting up the code example, based on OP's original code as [@Moob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1921385/moob) suggested.

```
<?php
 session_start();
include ('../includes/config.php'); 
include ('../includes/header.php'); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<!--start header-->
<div class="h_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
         <a href="index.php"><img src="../images/logo.png"> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cssmenu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
          <li  class="active"><a href="about.php"><span>About</span></a></li>
       <li class="has-sub"><a href="service.php"><span>Gallery</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="last"><a href="contact.php"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
     <div class="clear"></div>

                         <div class="search">
                    <h2>search</h2>
            <form>
                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Your search...">
                <input type="submit" value="">
            </form>
        </div>

                                         <div class="search1">

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];



    $password = strip_tags($password); 
$password = md5($password); // md5 is used to encrypt your password to make it more secure.





    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows!=0)
    {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $dbusername=$row['username'];
    $dbpassword=$row['password'];
    }

    if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword)
    {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['sess_user']=$username;

    /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: member.php");
    }
    } else {
    echo "<div class='results'>Invalid username or password</div>";
    }

} else {
    echo "All fields are required!";
}
}



?>                                       

            <h2>login/Register</h2>

            <form action="" method="POST">

            <label>Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="password" name="username" required />
            <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" class="submit" />
                <br><br>
                <center>
                <h2><p><a href="register.php">Register</a></p></h2>
                </center>
    </form> 
    </div>

    </div>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- start content -->
<div class="content_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <h2 class="style">About us</h2>
        <div class="about">
             <div class="cont-grid-img img_style">
                <img src="../images/about_pic.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
           <div class="cont-grid">
           <div class="abt-style">
            <p class="style top">We are a company built on dreams. And these dreams inspire us to create innovative products that enhance human mobility and benefit society. We see "The Power of Dreams" as a way of thinking that guides us and inspires us to move forward. The strength of our company comes from this philosophy—based on the visionary principles of our founder, Soichiro Honda.Our success in the global marketplace is the result of our continued investment in America's future. We thank our customers for the support and trust they've shown us. We look forward to challenging ourselves to create new products and services that bring value to our customers and society during the next 50 years.</p>
            </div>
             <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="about-p top">
                <p class="style">Honda's global lineup consists of the Fit, Civic, Accord, Insight, CR-V, CR-Z, Legend and two versions of the Odyssey, one for North America, and a smaller vehicle sold internationally. An early proponent of developing vehicles to cater to different needs and markets worldwide, Honda's lineup varies by country and may have vehicles exclusive to that region. A few examples are the latest Honda Odyssey minivan and the Ridgeline, Honda's first light-duty uni-body pickup truck. Both were designed and engineered primarily in North America and are produced there. Other example of exclusive models includes the Honda Civic five-door hatchback sold in Europe.

Honda's automotive manufacturing ambitions can be traced back to 1963, with the Honda T360, a kei car truck built for the Japanese market.[27] This was followed by the two-door roadster, the Honda S500 also introduced in 1963. In 1965, Honda built a two-door commercial delivery van, called the Honda L700. Honda's first four-door sedan was not the Accord, but the air-cooled, four-cylinder, gasoline-powered Honda 1300 in 1969. The Civic was a hatchback that gained wide popularity internationally, but it wasn't the first two-door hatchback built. That was the Honda N360, another Kei car that was adapted for international sale as the N600. The Civic, which appeared in 1972 and replaced the N600 also had a smaller sibling that replaced the air-cooled N360, called the Honda Life that was water-cooled.

The Honda Life represented Honda's efforts in competing in the kei car segment, offering sedan, delivery van and small pick-up platforms on a shared chassis. The Life StepVan had a novel approach that, while not initially a commercial success, appears to be an influence in vehicles with the front passengers sitting behind the engine, a large cargo area with a flat roof and a liftgate installed in back, and utilizing a transversely installed engine with a front-wheel-drive powertrain.</p>

        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="copy">
            <p class="w3-link">©&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="f_nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Skype</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Linked in</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's similar to position relative. If I go to a smaller window completely ruins it. :(

Comment: +1 for the updated part of this answer. You might want to flesh it out a bit and provide an example based on the OP's provided code.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using  css :after

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

```
.search1::after { 
    color: red;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold; 
    background: #232323;
    color:red;
    font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 150%;
    content: "your content here";
}
```

use script to hide or show it based upon php response.

Edit: whole code illustration

add this CSS:

```
.search1::after
{
  display:block;
  content:attr(data-content);
}

<?php
 session_start();
include ('../includes/config.php'); 
include ('../includes/header.php'); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<!--start header-->
<div class="h_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
         <a href="index.php"><img src="../images/logo.png"> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cssmenu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
          <li  class="active"><a href="about.php"><span>About</span></a></li>
       <li class="has-sub"><a href="service.php"><span>Gallery</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="last"><a href="contact.php"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
     <div class="clear"></div>

                         <div class="search">
                    <h2>search</h2>
            <form>
                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Your search...">
                <input type="submit" value="">
            </form>
        </div>

                                         <div class="search1">

            <h2>login/Register</h2>

            <form action="" method="POST">

            <label>Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="password" name="username" required />
            <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" class="submit" />
                <br><br>
                <center>
                <h2><p><a href="register.php">Register</a></p></h2>
                </center>
    </form> 
    </div>







<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];



    $password = strip_tags($password); 
$password = md5($password); // md5 is used to encrypt your password to make it more secure.





    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows!=0)
    {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $dbusername=$row['username'];
    $dbpassword=$row['password'];
    }

    if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword)
    {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['sess_user']=$username;

    /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: member.php");
    }
    } else {
    echo "$('.search1').attr('data-content','Your text Here');";
    }

} else {
    echo "All fields are required!";
}
}



?>
    </div>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- start content -->
<div class="content_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <h2 class="style">About us</h2>
        <div class="about">
             <div class="cont-grid-img img_style">
                <img src="../images/about_pic.jpg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
           <div class="cont-grid">
           <div class="abt-style">
            <p class="style top">We are a company built on dreams. And these dreams inspire us to create innovative products that enhance human mobility and benefit society. We see "The Power of Dreams" as a way of thinking that guides us and inspires us to move forward. The strength of our company comes from this philosophy—based on the visionary principles of our founder, Soichiro Honda.Our success in the global marketplace is the result of our continued investment in America's future. We thank our customers for the support and trust they've shown us. We look forward to challenging ourselves to create new products and services that bring value to our customers and society during the next 50 years.</p>
            </div>
             <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="about-p top">
                <p class="style">Honda's global lineup consists of the Fit, Civic, Accord, Insight, CR-V, CR-Z, Legend and two versions of the Odyssey, one for North America, and a smaller vehicle sold internationally. An early proponent of developing vehicles to cater to different needs and markets worldwide, Honda's lineup varies by country and may have vehicles exclusive to that region. A few examples are the latest Honda Odyssey minivan and the Ridgeline, Honda's first light-duty uni-body pickup truck. Both were designed and engineered primarily in North America and are produced there. Other example of exclusive models includes the Honda Civic five-door hatchback sold in Europe.

Honda's automotive manufacturing ambitions can be traced back to 1963, with the Honda T360, a kei car truck built for the Japanese market.[27] This was followed by the two-door roadster, the Honda S500 also introduced in 1963. In 1965, Honda built a two-door commercial delivery van, called the Honda L700. Honda's first four-door sedan was not the Accord, but the air-cooled, four-cylinder, gasoline-powered Honda 1300 in 1969. The Civic was a hatchback that gained wide popularity internationally, but it wasn't the first two-door hatchback built. That was the Honda N360, another Kei car that was adapted for international sale as the N600. The Civic, which appeared in 1972 and replaced the N600 also had a smaller sibling that replaced the air-cooled N360, called the Honda Life that was water-cooled.

The Honda Life represented Honda's efforts in competing in the kei car segment, offering sedan, delivery van and small pick-up platforms on a shared chassis. The Life StepVan had a novel approach that, while not initially a commercial success, appears to be an influence in vehicles with the front passengers sitting behind the engine, a large cargo area with a flat roof and a liftgate installed in back, and utilizing a transversely installed engine with a front-wheel-drive powertrain.</p>

        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="copy">
            <p class="w3-link">©&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="f_nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Skype</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Linked in</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you able to edit it using my code I've listed above? I'm just having trouble figuring it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Ariana and if you wanna remove text use : echo "$('.search1').attr('data-content','')";

Comment: I would avoid a javascript based solution unless you know for sure that all your users will have it available or have provided a fallback for those that dont.

Comment: @Moob have you read the code ? it is full of javascript :D i have just added one line of js to tens of original code.

Comment: It was more a recommendation than a criticism. The point being that whilst the page may behave differently with javascript the form itself should work regardless of whether the user has js or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the div in the form in the place you want it, set an id and in css set it to display none, then in the else block of your code where you now echo the div drop out of php and use js to show the div if theres an error. i.e

```
else{ ?>
      <script>document.getElementById("your_chosen_id").style.display="block";</script>
      <noscript><div class='results' style='position:relative;top:-200px;>Invalid    username or password</div></noscript>
<?php
```

### EDIT

Added noscript as Moob correctly pointed out that it obviously wouldn't work with js turned off.

Comment: Are you able to edit it using my code I've listed above? I'm just having trouble figuring it out. Thanks!

Comment: try this [paste bin link to code](http://pastebin.com/iwqDLvVf). I've added a <head> and <style> tag, take them out and put the #error_box in your stylesheet. I presume you have a head and title, meta tag in the original

Comment: Also don't use md5 for passwords, it's not secure. look into PHP bcrypt and sql is not secure, Look into PHP PDO prepared statements

Comment: You're an aboulute legend :)! But how do I move it a tad bit up? Would it still be in my results? in CSS

Comment: '#error_box{display:none;position:relative;top:-5px;}' Might work, not sure if you can set the position on something that is display:none; The other way would be give it a class error_box and set the css to .error_box{position:relative;top:-5px;}

Comment: Good Point Moob,Ariana add `<noscript><div class='results' style='position:relative;top:-200px;>Invalid username or password</div></noscript>
` after the script tags in the else section. You will have to play around with the position to get it right.

Comment: @Billy the downvote was mine for the JS solution. Add your noscript fallback to your answer and i'll remove it.